# How can I use single uniform variables inside this Vulkan shader?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have set up a shader like so. Instead of having all `projection` `view` `model` in a single object, I want to have them as separate bindings.

```
#version 450
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;
layout(binding = 0) uniform mat4 projection;
layout(binding = 1) uniform mat4 view;
layout(binding = 2) uniform mat4 model;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
void main() {
 gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
 fragColor = aColor;
}
```

However when compiling the shader I get the following errors:

```
main:4: error: 'non-opaque uniforms outside a block' : not allowed when using GLSL for Vulkan
main:4: error: 'binding' : requires block, or sampler/image, or atomic-counter type
main:5: error: 'non-opaque uniforms outside a block' : not allowed when using GLSL for Vulkan
main:5: error: 'binding' : requires block, or sampler/image, or atomic-counter type
main:6: error: 'non-opaque uniforms outside a block' : not allowed when using GLSL for Vulkan
main:6: error: 'binding' : requires block, or sampler/image, or atomic-counter type
```

How can I create individual bindings + set up individual `Descriptor Layout/Buffer/Pools/Sets`?

Comment: "error: 'non-opaque uniforms outside a block' : not allowed when using GLSL for Vulkan" suggests that the answer is "you can't", don't you think?

Comment: Maximus is right, you can't do this; you _need_ to use uniform blocks in Vulkan. It's the recommended way in GL(ES) too.